# Get Return value of sub shell script

Tags: bash, shell

I have a shell script, where i start a new .sh script.
Now I want to save the return value of the sub script in a variable.

I found this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
r=1
while [[ r -ne 0 ]]
do
r=`vx $* < \`tty\` > \`tty\``
done
exit 0
```

It calls the Script vx with a param and saves the return value in the variable r. What does the tty ... mean?
Is that the return value?
Can't I use $? for return value?

Thanks!

Edit:

So would be the following wrong?

```
#!/bin/bash

returnvalue=1

while  [ $returnvalue -ne 0 ]
do
    bash ./vx $1
    returnvalue=$?
done
```

Comment: have you tried ? this `r=$(vx $* < \`tty\` > \`tty\`; echo $?)`

Comment: I don't get it. What is the < `tty` > `tty`;?  Is r= $? wrong?

Answer (score 2):

I beleive you actually want:

```
#! /bin/sh -
until rv "$@"; do
  continue
done
```

You generally don't need to get the actual value of the exit status (`$?`) nor to know whether or not 0 means true or false. The `until`, `while`, `if`... construct take care of that. The `continue` above is only for legibility, you can put any command in there, include the no-op one: `:`.

Never use `$*` or `$@` unquoted, that doesn't make sense.

Answer (score 0):

You will save the output from the script in "r", the exit code would be in $?.

So just add a line before "done"

```
result=$?
```

Answer (score 0):

In the expression

```
r=`vx $* < \`tty\` > \`tty\``
```

Bash interprets `vx` as an executable filename to which you pass all (`$*`) of the arguments passed to the current script after shell expansion. For example, if the arguments to the script were `` * `ls /dev` `` then the argument list passed to vx will be the names of all of the files in the current directory plus the names of all of the files in `/dev`. The number of arguments will be the same as the number for file names.

`vx` is assumed to accept input on its standard input.

`tty` is an executable that returns a string that Bash interprets as a filename.

Note that the first invocation of `tty` could return a different filename than the second invocation' for example, if `tty` produces the filename based on some external condition such as the content of the file with the name produced by the previous invocation, or based on a timestamp or other external condition that could change.

The expression `` r=`...` `` assigns the standard output of the backticked command to `r`. The return value of the backticked expression is in `$?`.

Since the standard output of `vx` is redirected to the filename produced by the second invocation of `tty`, the value of `r` will always be empty (`r=`) which is the same as `r=0` in the expression `[[ r -ne 0 ]]`. The result is that there is no situation where the loop can run more than once.

Comment: `$*` is not the list of arguments, it's the list of files matching the patterns resulting from the further splitting of the arguments on the $IFS characters. You need `"$@"` for the list of arguments.

Comment: How could the two `tty` invocation return a different result? Their stdin is the same.

Comment: Very interesting analysis, but does that help OP with the problem?

Comment: @vonbrand The OP asked three questions. I believe I sepcifically replied to all of them.

Comment: @StephaneChazelas Thanks for noticing this point, I believe that my last edit "as a single string argument" fixes it.

Comment: Nope `"$*"` would be a single string argument. Try calling the script with those three arguments: `the-script 'a b' '*'` and see how many are passed to `rv`, and now compare with `"$@"`. `strace -fe execve` can help.